# How to print a list of numbers with the output format differing based on input?

Tags: c++, list, for-loop

Hello I'm writing a program that outputs different permutations of dice depending on how many dice you input. When outputting the results I'm trying to get it to output in a specific format but can't quite figure out how to get it to output correctly. For example, if there are 2 dice, an output would be (1,1) (1,2) (1,3)... 3 dice (1,1,1) (1,1,2) (1,1,3) and so on.

```
void printList(list<int>& dice, int ndie){
  list<int>::iterator it;
  for (it = dice.begin(); it != dice.end(); it++){
    for(int c = 1; c <= ndie; c++){
      if (c == 1){
        cout << "(";
      }
      else if(c == ndie){
        cout << ")";
      }
      else if(c > 1 && c != ndie) {
        cout << *it << ",";
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

I already have the permuting function, this is just the printing function i'm trying to build, however the output comes out as (for number of dice 3) (1,)(1,)(1,)(1,)(1,)(2,)(1,)(1,)(3,)... ect.

I've been messing with it for a few days and just can't nail it.
It's clear the permuting function works fine I just can't figure out how to print it in the correct format. Thanks.

Comment: Print `(` before the for loop and `)` after it. Inside the for loop print a comma if it isn't the first item and always print the item. You might consider a [mcve] that shows what's in the list and how you're calling this along with the expected output for that list configuration. It would help to remove any guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is almost correct. To get it 100% correct you just need to make three very simple, observations.

1. The character that appears before the first dice is always `(`
2. The character that appears before the 2nd and subsequent dice is always `,`
3. The character that appears after all dice values is `)`

Additionally, this algorithm doesn't need to know, at all, in advance, how many dice values there are. This appears to be an extra parameter to the function, and it is completely irrelevant. This logic has no need to know this information separately. All that needs to be done is, simply, to translate the above three, basic, elementary rules directly into C++ code.

```
  char ch='(';

  for (it = dice.begin(); it != dice.end(); it++){
    cout << ch << *it;
    ch = ',';
  }
  cout << ')';
```

This presumes that the list is not empty. If you'd like to get a meaningful result, like `()` in case of an empty list, a small tweak will be needed to handle that, too. But this is out of scope of the described task.